# Showing only survey questions in page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, survey

I have created a survey named Feedbacks. Now I want to add it into a page.

What I have done:

Edit Page > Insert> App Part > Feedbacks

Results

[image]

But I want the following view

[image]

This view comes after clicking on the Respond this Survey. But I want it initially. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via SharePoint Designer you could add `New Item Form` ([DataFormWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.aspx)) on the page

Steps

1. Under tab `Insert` select `New Item From` and `Custom List Form`  as demonstrated on picture below

   [image]
2. Specify list form parameters and click on ok button.

   [image]

Result
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add the page viewer webpart to the page and link the new form url:

URL: http://www.yoursharepoint.com/Lists/surve/NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eyoursharepoint%2Ecom